cellTowers list, unable to provide the data requested (cellid, mcc, mnc...)
I'm trying to implement the geolocation API. It requests the following data:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/requests-geolocation#cell_tower_object
Now my modem provides this information (cellid, mcc, lac and mnc) only for the connected tower.
For the rest of towers I can only obtain the earfcn and pci.
Has anyone faced the same issue? Any workaround to "convert" these parameters into the ones requested by google?
The AT+CENG command of my modem only returns complete information for the connected cell:
+CENG: 0,"1301,433,-101,-65,-20,-1,8662,20488458,214,07,255"

This is the template:
+CENG:<cell>,"<earfcn>,<pci>,<rsrp>,<rssi>,<rsrq>,<sinr>,<tac>,<cellid>,<mcc>,<mnc>,<tx power>"

For the rest of cells I get only basic information:
+CENG: 1,"1301,46,-100,-70,-20,-2"
+CENG: 2,"1301,251,-109,-70,-20,-1"
+CENG: 3,"1301,184,-104,-73,-20,-4"

